# Which assert method should I use to pass my api store test?

Tags: php, api, testing

I am trying to pass my testStoreUser() method and am having issues with which assert statement to use. The password I am using the API route instead to the server route with hash.
Here is my testStoreUser():

```
 public function testStoreUser()
    {
        //Arrange
        $data = [
            'data' => [
                'name' => 'Testing Name',
                'email' => 'myTesting@email.com',
                'password' => 'Harley81',
            ],
        ];

        //Act
        $response = $this->postJson('/api/users/', $data);

        //Assert
        $response
            ->assertStatus(201)
            ->assertJsonStructure([
                'data' => [
                    'name',
                    'email',
                    'password',
                    ]
            ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', $data['data']);
    }
```

Here is my api/user controller specifically the store function:

```
 /**
     * Store a newly created user in storage.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return UserResource
     */
    public function store(Request $request): UserResource
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'data' => 'required|array',
            'data.name'=> 'required|string',
            'data.email'=> 'required|string',
            'data.password' => ['required', Password::min(8)->mixedCase()],
        ]);

        $user = new User();

        $user->fill($validated['data'])->saveOrFail();

        return new UserResource($user);
    }
```

And this is current error I am getting:

```
Failed asserting that an array has the key 'password'.
 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/AssertableJsonString.php:256
 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/AssertableJsonString.php:241
 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/AssertableJsonString.php:254
 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php:795
 /var/www/html/tests/Feature/UserApiTest.php:49
```

Comment: do you want to assert your password value or the array of the response?

Comment: Assert the array of the response.

Comment: May i see your `$response` value (after hitting the route)?

Comment: The error I am getting?

Comment: Just after `$response = $this->postJson('/api/users/', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed this in my test.

```
      $response
            ->assertStatus(201)
            ->assertJson([
                'data' => [
                    'name' => $data['data']['name'],
                    'email' => $data['data']['email'],
                ]
            ]);
```